# Question about random variables operations

Tags: statistics, random-variables

[image]

As we can see in the picture above, what we call *random variables* looks like much more like a function, in the way that there is an input and then this random variable perfoms a process and gives as output a *value* (number). So, what i can't understand is how operations can be made between random variables. Like, it makes sense when you add 2 + 2 and you get 4 as result. But when you are adding random variables it's like you're squaring a sum $ x^{+} $, taking the square root of a factorial $ \sqrt{!} $ or in the statistical field indeed, summing the height of one person with the weight of another. I mean, you are processing a process! For example, I have an exercise where it is asked if it is true or false that if $ X \sim U(0;1) $ then  $ 1 - X \sim X $. Another one asks if $ X $ and $ Y $ are iid $ Poi(1) $ then $ X - Y = 0 $. Anyway, i think i've made my point! Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A random variable is indeed a function.  it's a set function,  it assigns to each subset of the sample space a real number.

Adding two random variables works just like adding two functions we DEFINE $f+g$ to be the function that for any input x,  outputs $f(x)+g(x)$.

so in this case, the sum of two random variables is a new random variable...it takes the input set,  runs it through the two random variables, adds the result, and outputs that result

Edit to address question: Constants are random variables as well, they input a set and output the constant.
So, if you have a random variable X,  1-X is a new random variable, it inputs any measurable subset of your sample space,  and outputs the real number 1-X(of that set)

Comment: But Alan what would it mean so to subtract a random variable from 1 like in the given example $ 1 - X $ ? Does it mean to subtract one for each $ x $ of $ X $?

Comment: 1 is a random variable as well,    It takes in any set and outputs 1.   (I.e. its a constant).  So 1-X takes in a set and outputs 1-X(that set)

Answer (score 1):

Random variables are indeed measurable functions from a Probability space to the real line with its Borel $\sigma$-field.

Two random variables can be added, multiplied and composed just like addition, multiplication and composition of functions.

Suppose $f,g$ are two functions then $f+g,f.g,f\circ g$ are defined as
$$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$$$$(f.g)(x)=f(x).g(x)$$$$(f\circ g)(x)=f(g(x))$$
and denoted as the sum, product and composition of $f$ and $g$ respectively.

I hope you can now understand how to deal with random variables.

Comment: They can't be composed,   as the input of a random variable is a subset of the probability space and the output is a real number.  $g(x)$ is a real number, and thus can't be inputted into f

Comment: I didn't talk about composition of two random variables. I mentioned composition of functions so that $g(X)$, where $X$ is a random variable and $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow$(some set), is well-defined.

Comment: Umm, yes you did.   "Two random variables can be added, multiplied, and composed just like addition, multiplication, and composition of functions"

Comment: sorry! typo...but I didn't mean that.